# Cross-Forest Trust

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012, active-directory

I am looking at testing a cross-domain trust we can have two domain controllers (with different forests and domain names) setup so we can move everyone onto the new domain.

We do NOT run exchange on site and we do not have any links to O365 to AD currently.

Onto the problem:

I have setup two DCs in a Virtual Machine:
They are on the same network 192.168.0.*

1. The Windows 2003 server:
   Name: OLDSRVR
   "Clone" of our current Domain Controller
   IP: 192.168.0.1
   Domain: internal.test.com
2. The Windows 2012 server:
   Name: ADCTEST01
   Brand new domain setup from scratch separate to internal.test.com
   Domain: internal.test2.com
   IP: 192.168.0.2

Both have different MAC addresses

OLDSRVR can only see ADCTEST if it has dynamic IP set.
If I set a static IP it cannot see it.

If I try using the dynamic IP and try to join it gets to the end then complains "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed"

However I am able to connect onto each AD and browse the contents if I ignore the error... very odd.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the MAC addresses of both OLDSRVR and the current domain controller. They may be the same, which will cause conflicts.

Comment: Hi David,

Thanks for that suggestion - they both have different MACs.